# In what sense is the set of density matrices compact in infinite dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, density-operator, quantum-states

Consider a complex, infinite-dimensional and separable Hilbert space $H$ and let $\mathcal I(H)$ denote the space of trace-class operators. The set of density operators $$\mathcal S(H):= \{\rho\in \mathcal I(H)\,|\, \mathrm{Tr}\rho=1\, , \, \rho \geq 0 \}$$

enjoys certain nice mathematical and physical features, some explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121337/density-matrix-formalism). Moreover, it is well-known that $\mathcal S(H)$ is compact for a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, as discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/774436/is-the-set-of-density-matrices-on-a-d-dimensional-hilbert-space-compact).

**Question:** Is there a notion in which the set of density matrices is compact for an infinite-dimensional $H$? For example, in Ref. 1 it is stated (right after discussing the finite-dimensional case) that

> $[\ldots]$ by using a physically natural topology (weak topology for $\rho$) one can still show that $\mathcal S(H)$ is compact.

In which topology is $\mathcal S(H)$ compact and how is it proved? Further, what makes this topology physically natural?

**Edit:** In Ref. 2, there is a theorem: $\mathcal S(H)$ is a compact convex subset of the real vector space $\mathcal I(H)$, and a proof which goes like this:

> Now $\mathcal S(H)\subset \mathcal I(H)=\mathcal B_*(H)$ is a closed unit ball (because $||\rho||_1=\mathrm{Tr}\rho=1$ for all $\rho \in \mathcal S(H)$). Therefore, $\mathcal S(H)$ is weakly compact in the space $\mathcal I(H)$ by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem $[\ldots]$.

But I don't really understand the proof.

---

References:

1. *Decoherence Suppression in Quantum Systems 2008. World Scientific Publishing. Editors: Mikio Nakahara, Robabeh Rahimi, Akira SaiToh. Page 12*
2. *Theory of Quantum Information with Memory. M. H. Chang. 2022. De Gruyter. Section 2.4. Page 54, Proposition 2.4.2*

Comment: It seems like they are referring to the weak operator topology, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology. According to that wiki page, every norm-bounded set is compact in this topology.

Comment: Hi @Noiralef, thanks for your comment. I cannot quite follow the article (in particular, I am a bit confused comparing this to other statements...). Can you expand your comment in a (more detailed) answer?

Comment: @Noiralef See the discussion below to see some of my doubts.

Comment: I have been following the discussion with interest, but my operator theory lectures were quite a while ago...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assertion is **false**, if I understand well it.

First of all some general information on the notion of weak * topology.

One has a (complex) normed space $B$ and its topological dual $B'$ which is, by definition the vector space of continuous linear maps $f: B \to \mathbb{C}$.

This space has a natural structure of normed space as well with the norm
$$||f||' := \sup\{|f(x)| \:|\: x \in B \:, ||x||=1\}\:.$$
However we can equip $B'$ with another seminormed topology induced by $B$ called **weak * topology**, it is characterized by the fact that

$$B' \ni f_n \to f \in B'\quad iff \quad f_n(x)-f(x)\to 0 \quad \forall x\in B\:.$$

The **Banach-Alaoglu theorem** proves that every norm-closed ball in $B'$
$$\{f \in B' \:|\: ||f|| \leq r\}$$
is compact with respect to the weak * topology provided $B$ is complete (i.e. is a Banach space).

Sometimes it happens that two normed spaces $B_1$ and $B_2$ are in topological duality, that is one is (normed-space) isomorphic to the topological dual of the other. If $B_2$ is isomorphic through $F$  to $B_1' = F(B_2)$, the action of the elements of $B_2$ o the elements of $B_1$ is indicated by means of a pairing:
$$\langle b_1, b_2\rangle := (F(b_2))(b_1)\:.$$

Let us pass to the discussed assertion, that the space of the mixed states $S(H)$ is compact with respect to some weak * topology on that. The space $S(H)$ is not linear and it is not a closed ball of
the normed (Banach) space of the trace class operators $B_1(H)$ equipped with its natural norm topology induced by the notion of trace.
Therefore, one should try to prove that  $S(H)$ is a compact subset of $B_1(H)$.

From the sketch of proof, it seems that the authors use the fact that $B_1(H)$ is the topological dual space of some other space. All that in order to apply the Banach-Alaoglu theorem as written above.(*)

As is well known, $B_1(H)$ is in fact (isometrically isomorphic to) the topological dual space of   $B_\infty(H)$ (the Banach space of compact operators with the natual norm operator topology).

The duality is represented in terms of the *trace operation* as $B_1(H)$ is a (both sides *) ideal, as the (left-continuous) pairing

$$\langle A, B \rangle := tr(AB)\:,\:\quad A\in B_1(H)\:, \quad B \in B_\infty(H)$$

The Banach-Alaoglu theorem proves that every closed ball in $B_1(H)$ is therefore compact with respect to the weak * topology induced by the topological duality considered above. In particular, according to this weak* topology,
$$B_1(H) \ni \rho_n \to \rho \in B_1(H)\quad iff \quad tr((\rho_n-\rho)A)\to 0 \quad \forall A\in B_1(H)$$
To conclude the proof it would be sufficient to prove that $S(H)$ is closed with respect to that topology, since closed subsets of compact sets are compact as well.

But it is not the case as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783685/compactness-of-subset-of-trace-class-operators-on-a-hilbert-space)!

On the other hand, *since weak * topology is Hausdorff*, compact sets are closed. This proves that the assertion, referred to the said weak * topology,  is **false** as $S(H)$ is not closed with respect to that weak * topology.

Maybe the assertion is true using another weak (natural?) topology.

---

($*$) Another possibility, not followed by the authors, is to see $B_1(H) \subset B(H)$ and viewing $B(H)$ as the dual of $B_1(H)$, thus equipping this latter with the weak* topology of $B(H)$ also known as ultraweak topology.

Even another way is to see $B_1(H)$ as subset of $B_2(H)$ the Hilbert-space space of Hilbert Schmidt operators and to use the weak * topology  on $B_2(H)$ induced by the Riesz anti isomorphism.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, let me quote the version of the B-A theorem used in the book (which I also find highly unusual, since e.g. we consider here Banach and not Hilbert spaces), from p. 7, theorem 1.1.4: *The closed unit ball of a Hilbert space is weakly compact*.

Comment: There is no Hilbert space structure in these spaces of operators, unless using the Hilbert-Schmidt class. But the sketch of proof does not seem to follow that way...

Comment: Thanks for the summary of the relevant ideas here, much appreciated. You write: "Therefore () should be viewed as a (compact) subset of 1()." - you presumably mean convex instead of compact, no?

Comment: Not only convex, the thesis is that it is compact, no?

Comment: Maybe "viewed" is misleading. I correct

Comment: The two answers to this question do not contradict each other, right? The weak operator topology is different from the weak* operator topology.

Comment: Yes they are different.   Actually also the other answer does not prove that the thesis is correct, just because the usula remark: $S(H)$ is not  even closed  with respect to the weak operator topology on $B(H)$.

Comment: However the weak * topology used in my answer is not the weak * operator topology (the ultraweak topology)! I know it is a tragedy... The weak * operator topology is defined on $B(H)$ viewing it as the dual of $B_1(H)$. I instead used a weak * topology induced on $B_1(H)$, vieweing it as the dual of $B_\infty(H)$.

Comment: Hi. I've corrected some typos and made one small correction. Hope that was okay. Thanks again for the discussion.

Comment: It's OK, of course. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Given two topologies $\mathcal O_1$ and $\mathcal O_2$ on the same set, we say that $\mathcal O_1$ is *weaker* (or *coarser*) than $\mathcal O_2$ if $\mathcal O_1\subset \mathcal O_2$ - in other words, every set which is open in $\mathcal O_1$ is open in $\mathcal O_2$. The descriptor "weak" comes from the fact that is in some sense less stringent; a function which is continuous in $\mathcal O_2$ is necessarily continuous in $\mathcal O_1$, and a sequence which converges in $\mathcal O_2$ necessarily converges in $\mathcal O_1$, but the reverse implications do not generally hold.

The weak operator topology $\mathcal O_W$ on the set of bounded operators $B(\mathscr H)$ is defined to be the weakest topology such that, for any $x,y\in \mathscr H$, the map
$$f_{xy}:B(\mathscr H)\rightarrow \mathbb C$$
$$T\mapsto \langle x, Ty\rangle$$
is continuous. In terms of open sets, a set $U\subseteq B(\mathscr H)$ is open in the weak operator topology if, for all $x,y\in \mathscr H$, there exists some open set $V\subseteq \mathbb C$ such that $f_{xy}^{-1}(V) = U$.

In contrast, note that the *strong* operator topology $\mathcal O_S$ - which is the topology on $B(\mathscr H)$ induced by the operator norm - also satisfies the condition that each $f_{xy}$ is continuous, but is *stronger* (or *finer*) than $\mathcal O_W$ in the sense that all open sets in $\mathcal O_W$ are also open in $\mathcal O_S$ but the reverse is not true.

---

Compactness of $\mathcal S(\mathscr H)$ in $\mathcal O_W$ can be shown by defining the function

$$\pi : \mathscr B_1 \rightarrow \prod_{x,y\in \mathscr H} D_{\Vert x\Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert}$$
$$ T\mapsto \langle x,Ty\rangle$$

where
$$\mathscr B_1 = \bigg\{T\in B(\mathscr H) \ : \ \Vert T\Vert_{op} \leq 1\bigg\}$$ is the unit ball in $B(\mathscr H)$ and $D_{\Vert x\Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert } \subset \mathbb C$ is the disk (centered at 0) with radius $\Vert x\Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert$. For whatever scant intuition you can find, this maps each operator in $\mathscr B_1$ to the list of all possible matrix elements.

From here, the logic goes roughly as follows:

1. The image $\pi(\mathscr B_1)$ is closed because it contains all of its limit points, by the definition of the weak operator topology.
2. The product of disks is compact (in the usual product topology), and a closed subset of a compact set is compact, so $\pi(\mathscr B_1)$ is compact.
3. $\pi$ constitutes a homeomorphism between $B_1$ and its image. This is not immediately trivial, but is not so hard to prove. Intuitively, it is invertible because a list of all possible matrix elements uniquely defines an operator, and continuous (with continuous inverse) due to the definition of $\mathcal O_W$. As a result, $\mathscr B_1$ is compact in $\mathcal O_W$.

### ***To Be Finished ...***

---

To answer your question about the physical relevance of this topology, note that the observable characteristics of an operator can all be framed in terms of its matrix elements. Loosely, a sequence of bounded operators converges in the weak operator topology if and only if all of its matrix elements (and therefore observable characteristics) converge.

As a toy example. consider an orthonormal basis $\phi_i, i\in \mathbb N$ and the sequence of shift operators $T_n: \phi_i \mapsto \phi_{i+n}$.  Given any physical state vector $\psi = \sum_i c_i \phi_i$, the sequence $c_i$ must converge to zero. For sufficiently large $n$, the overlap between $\psi$ and $T_n\psi$ becomes smaller and smaller as $n$ increases. It is clear that the sequence $T_n$ does not converge in the strong operator topology, but it *does* converge in the weak operator topology because for all $x,y\in \mathscr H$, the sequence $\langle x, T_ny\rangle \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Hi J. Murray, thank you very much for your effort! I have some questions (but not much time right now, I'll write later some more). But to start with, I don't think that the set of density operators is closed in the weak operator topology. Take any orthonormal basis and define the projectors $P_n:=|e_n\rangle\langle e_n|$; then $P_n \to 0$ in WOT (which should follow from Bessel's inequality). Or do I misunderstand something? If I am wrong here, would you mind to outline a proof that $\mathcal S(H)$ is closed? Thanks! With WOT I mean$T_n\to T$ iff $\langle x,T_ny\rangle\to \langle x,Ty\rangle$

Comment: @TobiasFünke Indeed, you're right about that. Apologies, I wrote this before heading out the door and that was a silly error - closure is not the correct property here, I will attempt to correct it later in the day when I have time.

Comment: Thanks. In case you are interested, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783685/compactness-of-subset-of-trace-class-operators-on-a-hilbert-space) yesterday on MathSE. When I encountered the quote I first thought they'd mean this topology, but it turns out that the set is not closed either (same counter example).

Comment: Indeed I was about trying the same proof. Actually,weak compactness of any closed norm ball is guaranteed by the Banach-Alaouglu theorem. The difficult point is weak closedness of the set of density matrices, that is false.  My feeling is that  the the overall assertion is false.

Comment: Compactness arises from a weak topology and the Banach-Alaouglu theorem, so we should view $B_1(H)$ (the space of the trace class operators) as the **topological dual** of some Banach space of operators. That is the right issue.

Comment: @ValterMoretti After some thought, I am beginning to think the same. I’m interested to think about it a bit more.

Comment: Maybe there is some hope.... Actually $B_1(H)$ is the topological dual of  the space of compact operators equipped with the stanadard operator norm.  It can be therefore equipped with the weak star topology. $\rho_n \to \rho$ all trace class if $tr(\rho_nA) \to tr(\rho A)$ for every compact operator. Is $S(H)$ closed with respect to the associated topology? Now   $\rho$ must be trace class, so that the found conterexample does not work.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Isn't this what I've tried in the MathSE link?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did not catch the point. But this is not the way tried above by J. Murray!

Comment: However the objection is similar.

Comment: J. Murray used the weak topology on $B_1(H) \subset B(H)$, this latter viewed as the topological dual of $B_1(H)$.  You used $B_1(H)$ as the topological dual of $B_\infty(H)$ (compact operators).  Some minutes ago I tried another way passing through the Hilbert-Schmidt operators, but I did not managed to prove the result. I suspect that it is false. Or, at least, there is no a "natural" topology that proves the assertion.

Comment: @ValterMoretti  Yes, I agree with you. If you want to (and have time to) write down your thoughts in an answer (perhaps elaborating a bit more the problem(s)), I'd appreciate it. See the recent edit, where I quoted the proof given in a reference. Thanks to both of you so far for helping me. I nearly lost my mind...I also wondered why it is so hard to find a reference for this claim.

Comment: @Tobias Funke I think that the assertion is false if referred to that topology. I wrote a proof of this fact in my answer.