# Degrees of freedom of a $d$ level system and the dimension of its Bloch manifold

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, group-theory, lie-algebra, density-operator

A qubit is described by two independent degrees of freedom that parametrize the Bloch sphere.

**Question**:
For a level $d$ level system, i.e., a qu$d$it, what are the corresponding degrees of freedom? And what is the dimension of its Bloch manifold?

---

*Naively*, we know that given a qu$d$it state $|d\rangle$ we can easily formulate its $d\times d$ density matrix as $|d\rangle \langle d| := \rho_d$.

*Given it is a Hermitian matrix*, an element of $SU(d),$  we have $d^2-1$ degrees of freedom. This matches the dimension of the adjoint representation of the corresponding Lie algebra and makes sense since we should be able to write $\rho_d$ as a linear superposition of the $d^2-1$ generators.

However, not all angles in the $SU(d) \subset SO(d^2-1)$ manifold are allowed. For example, just like for a qubit, the trace constraint ${\rm Tr}(\rho_d)=1$ will remove a degree of freedom. Furthermore, $\rho_d$ is a Positive Semidefinite matrix (PSD) and I am not sure if further degrees are removed because of this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The space of *pure* states on a $d$-dimensional system is the complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^{d-1}$, which is a manifold with real dimension $2d-2$ (and also a $(d-1)$-dimensional [complex manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_manifold)).
2. The space of all $d$-dimensional states, that is, the set of unit-trace positive semidefinite $d\times d$ Hermitian matrices, is a convex (compact) subset of the $(d^2-1)$-dimensional *affine subspace* of unit-trace Hermitian matrices. Note that neither of these are vector spaces. The former is a compact subset, and the latter is an an *[affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space)*. This $(d^2-1)$-dimensional affine subspace is embedded in the $d^2$-dimensional (real) *vector space* of Hermitian $d\times d$ matrices.
3. Absolutely all unitary operations (of suitable dimension) are allowed. The trace constraint is automatically maintained in all cases, because $\operatorname{Tr}(U\rho U^\dagger)=\operatorname{Tr}(\rho)$ for any (special or not) unitary operation $U\in\mathbf{U}(d)$. In fact, if you consider the space of all states, unitary operations will also only connect specific subsets of states; more precisely, they will create disjoint orbits of states sharing the same purity.
4. I mostly already implicitly said this above, but let me stress that $\mathbf{SU}(d)$ is the (Lie) group of special unitary matrices, not the space of Hermitian matrices. Its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(d)$ is *kinda* the same as the space of Hermitian matrices, but with the notable difference that while these are isomorphic as real vector spaces, only one of them has a Lie algebra structure.
5. The PSD constraint doesn't actually remove degrees of freedom, but rather imposes further constraints that make the set of states compact. See *e.g.* *[Why does the space of pure qudit states have dimension $2(D-1)$, rather than $D^2-2$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/398114/58382)* and *[Characterisation of the generalised Bloch space in spherical coordinates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/424667/58382)*.
   In the case of a single qubit, the PSD constraint is what brings you from a full vector space to a finite-volume sphere.